# The 3n+1 solution overflows in C++ VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, overflow

I'm trying to solve the 3n+1 problem using VS2010 c++,in small inputs it works well,but when it reaches 113383 it overflows.

Here is the [problem link](http://acm.uva.es/p/v1/100.html).

This is the code I'm using to solve this problem :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    while (!cin.eof()) {
        int i, j, maxCycle = 0, tmaxCycle = 0;
        cin >> i >> j;
        for (int x = i; x <= j; x++) {
            int n = x;
            tmaxCycle = 0;
            while (n != 1) {
                if ((float)(n/2) != (n/2.0)) {
                    n = 3*n + 1;
                }
                else {
                    n /= 2;
                }
                tmaxCycle += 1;
                if (n < 0) {
                    int blah = 0; //just for the breakpoint
                } 
            }
            tmaxCycle += 1;
            if (tmaxCycle > maxCycle) {
                maxCycle = tmaxCycle;
            }
        }
        cout << i << "\t" << j << "\t" << maxCycle << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I made a breakpoint  at line 15,and in this point values overflows

```
n=-1812855948
```

Comment: What inputs do you give to make it overflow?

Comment: use 64 bit unsigned integers.  If those overflow, use a bignum library.

Comment: @japreiss it worked using unsigned long int,put it in an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 64-bit unsigned integers.  If those overflow, use a bignum library like the [GNU Multiple Precision Library](http://gmplib.org/).  Bignums give you unlimited precision and size.

Comment: 64 bits should be sufficient. The hailstone sequence doesn't go higher than 2^36 for any number under a million. Although, makes me wonder why the problem linked says "You can assume that no operation overflows a 32-bit integer" when that's clearly false.

Comment: that's exactly why i asked this questions

Comment: They probably meant a 32-bit *unsigned* integer.  `Unsigned long int` is still 32-bit on some systems.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
if((float)(n/2)!=(n/2.0))
```

produces incorrect results, long before `int` overflows. Change it to

```
if ( n & 1)
```

Comment: it also produces the same problem
    n=-1812855948